# Mutt, GMail and multiple accounts

Tags: email, gmail, mutt

I have a work-related email and my private GMail account.
Through `fetchmail` and `procmail` I fetch the work-related email and deliver it into m GMail account. In GMail, I have configured the SMTP for my work email, so that I can answer the work emails from within GMail.

I want to move to `mutt`. For the moment, I can handle the reception of emails (since all reach GMail).
I would like to answer using my work-related email, and furthermore, to emulate the fact that when I use that alias in GMail it leaves a copy in my mailbox.

Is this possible with `mutt`?

Comment: Just curious: did you resolve this?

Comment: No, I have not figured it out, yet.